# sidewaystable in the list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Sorry if this question is silly but I am still kinda new to LaTeX.

How can I manage a sidewaystable to appear in the `\listoftables`?

My normal tables appear in the list but not the sideways one.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}\centering
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}% adjust the L and R margins by 1 inch
\begin{scriptsize}
\label{Planificacion de tiempos}
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[RGB]{192,217,217}} m{3 cm}|>{\columncolor[RGB]{219,219,112}}m{3 cm}|>{\columncolor[RGB]{192,217,217}} m{3 cm}|>{\columncolor[RGB]{219,219,112}}m{3 cm}|>{\columncolor[RGB]{192,217,217}} m{3 cm}|>{\columncolor[RGB]{219,219,112}}m{3 cm}|} \hline
\begin{center}\textbf{Proyecto de explotar la imagen del producto}}\end{center} & \begin{center}\textbf{Proyecto integral de servicios}\end{center} & \begin{center}\textbf{Proyecto posicionar la imagen de la empresa en el mercado}\end{center} & \begin{center}\textbf{Proyecto de incremento de infraestructura}\end{center} & \begin{center}\textbf{Proyecto de capacitacion y desarrollo}\end{center} & \begin{center}\textbf{Proyecto de gestion de procdimientos}\end{center} \\ \hline

Mejor rendimiento / km & Trato personalizado & Originalidad & Se cuenta con medios suficientes para llevar a cabo el trabajo & Capacitacion fuel Injetion & Diferentes tipos de distribucion \\ \hline %1
Durabilidad en el producto & Excelente trato & Puntualidad en la fecha de entrega de la moto & No hay rampas para descargar las motos & Mayor experiencia en los tecnicos & Identidad departamental \\ \hline %2
Motos Japonesas & Curso de manejo seguro de motocicletas & Prestigio de la marca & No hay herramienta suficiente & Enviar a una estancia  a los tecnicos & Control de almacen \\ \hline %3
Escases de motos en exhibicion & Felicitar en onomastico & Las mejores instalaciones de taller & Sin computadora para el taller & Crecimiento laboral & Reducir los requisitos para credito \\ \hline %4
&  Recibir cualquier marca de motos & La empresa sabe donde quiere ir & Falta de equipo & Mayor convivencia & Incrementar el volumen de ventas para obtener mayores utilidades \\ \hline %5 
&  Realizar visitas mas constantes & Se brinda confianza y seguridad &  &  Falta de capacitacion por areas & Recuperar pagos vencidos \\ \hline %6 
&  Ser complaciemnte con los clientes & Mayor penetracion en el mercado & & Sin cursos de ingles & Mayor accesibilidad en piezas \\ \hline %7 
&  Mejorar el servicio postventa & Promocion de eventos &  & Poco personal de ventas para abrir mercado & Ofrecer buenos financiamientos \\ \hline %8 
&  Dar confianza al cliente y total satisfaccion al cliente & Publicitar y comparar nuestros precios con la competencia &  & Falta de comunicación & Dar facilidades de credito \\ \hline %9 
& Mejorar la calidad en el servicio & Satisfaccion en la marca y servicios &   & Comprension y entendimiento & Tener Variedad de Productos \\ \hline %10 
& No hay transporte para motos & Convencer a los corporativos de compra &   &   & Implementar sustentabilidad \\ \hline %11
& Falta atencion y seguimiento & Promociones en genersal &   &   & Bajo stock \\ \hline %12 
& Dejar ir al cliente & Presencia en las redes sociales &   &   & No hay pronostico de venta\\ \hline %13 
& Debil negociacion con el cliente & Realizar tandas de motos &   &   & Incumplimiento del tiempo de entrega \\ \hline %14 
& & Pocos eventos competitivos &   &   & Costo de servicio alto \\ \hline %15 
& & Competencia en calidad con otras marcas &   &   & Deficiencia en el servicio interno \\ \hline %16 
& & Precios de la competencia &   &   & La competencia tiene enganches menores \\ \hline %17
& & Falta de confianza &   &   &   \\ \hline %18
&  & Competidores (yamaha, honda) &   &   &   \\ \hline %19
&  & Frecuencia de los accidentes &   &   &   \\ \hline %20
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabla comparativa de proyectos utilizados en la enseñanza de sistemas operativos.}
\end{center}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

P.S.: The sideways table throws an error when compiling, but I ignore it and it show just like I want it, maybe it's related to that error?

Comment: It's enough to use `\caption` as you did in your snippet. Did you run your code twice? By the way, inside these environments, `\label` must go **after** `\caption`.

Comment: You have a spurious right brace at the end of `\textbf{Proyecto...}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thx so much!! i put \label after \caption and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate an entry in the list of tables, it's enough to use `\caption`inside the `sidewaystable` environment, as you did in your snippet. However, your code had some problems:

You had

```
\textbf{Proyecto de explotar la imagen del producto}}
```

and there's a spurious closing brace; it should be

```
\textbf{Proyecto de explotar la imagen del producto}
```

I also moved `\label` after `\caption`; otherwise the string picked up for cross-referencing the table will be wrong.

I also did some minor modifications:

`\scriptsize` is a font switch (a declaration).

I removed some `center` environments and replaced them with `\centering` commands (no extra vertical space added).

I used a new column type with a mandatory argument controlling the column color; I set the columns to be `\raggedright`(narrow columns will present problems with hyphenation and will produce overfull `\hbox`es).

Perhaps I did some other changes, but I cannot remember.

Here's the modified version of the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{192,217,217}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{219,219,112}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\columncolor{#1}\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}% adjust the L and R margins by 1 inch
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|L{myblue}|L{mygreen}|L{myblue}|L{mygreen}|L{myblue}|L{mygreen}|} \hline
\centering\textbf{Proyecto de explotar la imagen del producto} 
  & \centering\textbf{Proyecto integral de servicios} 
  & \centering\textbf{Proyecto posicionar la imagen de la empresa en el mercado}
  & \centering\textbf{Proyecto de incremento de infraestructura} 
  & \centering\textbf{Proyecto de capacitacion y desarrollo} 
 & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{Proyecto de gestion de procdimientos} \\ 
\hline
Mejor rendimiento / km & Trato personalizado & Originalidad 
  & Se cuenta con medios suficientes para llevar a cabo el trabajo 
  & Capacitacion fuel Injetion & Diferentes tipos de distribucion \\ 
\hline %1
Durabilidad en el producto & Excelente trato 
  & Puntualidad en la fecha de entrega de la moto 
  & No hay rampas para descargar las motos & Mayor experiencia en los tecnicos 
  & Identidad departamental \\ 
\hline %2
Motos Japonesas & Curso de manejo seguro de motocicletas & Prestigio de la marca 
  & No hay herramienta suficiente & Enviar a una estancia  a los tecnicos 
  & Control de almacen \\ 
\hline %3
Escases de motos en exhibicion & Felicitar en onomastico 
  & Las mejores instalaciones de taller & Sin computadora para el taller 
  & Crecimiento laboral & Reducir los requisitos para credito \\ 
\hline %4
&  Recibir cualquier marca de motos & La empresa sabe donde quiere ir 
  & Falta de equipo & Mayor convivencia 
  & Incrementar el volumen de ventas para obtener mayores utilidades \\ 
\hline %5 
&  Realizar visitas mas constantes & Se brinda confianza y seguridad 
  & & Falta de capacitacion por areas & Recuperar pagos vencidos \\ 
\hline %6 
& Ser complaciemnte con los clientes & Mayor penetracion en el mercado 
  & & Sin cursos de ingles & Mayor accesibilidad en piezas \\ 
\hline %7 
&  Mejorar el servicio postventa & Promocion de eventos 
  & & Poco personal de ventas para abrir mercado & Ofrecer buenos financiamientos \\ 
\hline %8 
&  Dar confianza al cliente y total satisfaccion al cliente 
  & Publicitar y comparar nuestros precios con la competencia 
  & & Falta de comunicación & Dar facilidades de credito \\ 
\hline %9 
& Mejorar la calidad en el servicio & Satisfaccion en la marca y servicios 
  & & Comprension y entendimiento & Tener Variedad de Productos \\ 
\hline %10 
& No hay transporte para motos & Convencer a los corporativos de compra 
  & & & Implementar sustentabilidad \\ 
\hline %11
& Falta atencion y seguimiento & Promociones en genersal 
  & & & Bajo stock \\ 
\hline %12 
& Dejar ir al cliente & Presencia en las redes sociales 
  & & & No hay pronostico de venta\\ 
\hline %13 
& Debil negociacion con el cliente & Realizar tandas de motos 
  & & & Incumplimiento del tiempo de entrega \\ 
\hline %14 
& & Pocos eventos competitivos & & & Costo de servicio alto \\ 
\hline %15 
& & Competencia en calidad con otras marcas & & & Deficiencia en el servicio interno \\ 
\hline %16 
& & Precios de la competencia & & & La competencia tiene enganches menores \\ 
\hline %17
& & Falta de confianza & & & \\ 
\hline %18
& & Competidores (yamaha, honda) & & & \\ 
\hline %19
& & Frecuencia de los accidentes & & & \\ 
\hline %20
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Tabla comparativa de proyectos utilizados en la enseñanza de sistemas operativos.}
\label{Planificacion de tiempos}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are my hero!! thx so much for the comment's of each modification you did. cheers!